# SQL how replace many "IF's" with an efficient query

Tags: sql, sql-server

it's required to get the salary but discounted from some statal entities (health and afp)
   this entities have differentes % of discount for example, and the ppl will have differents Afp and Health id, all mixed

- afp 1  5% dsct
- afp 2  10%
- afp 3  15% dsct

and

- health 1  7% dsct
- health 2  12% dsct
- health 3  18% dsct

how can I get the salary but not recurring to a many

```
IF (afp=1)
  IF (health=1)
  IF (health=2)
  IF (health=3)
IF (afp=2)
  IF (health=1)
  IF (health=2)
  IF (health=3)
```

and so on, is there a way to avoid these many IF'S? 
Hope you can help me guys, thnks

Comment: Sample data & expected results would be great

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when afp = 1 and health = 1 then 0.05
             when afp = 1 and health = 2 then 0.10
             when afp = 1 and health = 3 then 0.15
             when afp = 2 and health = 1 then 0.07
             when afp = 2 and health = 2 then 0.12
             when afp = 2 and health = 3 then 0.18
        end) as discount
```

Or a reference table, which you can build on the fly:

```
select t.*, v.discount
from t left join
     (values (1, 1, 0.05), (1, 2, 0.10), . . .
     ) v(afp, health, discount)
     on t.afp = v.afp and t.health = v.health
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is `choose()`

**Example**

```
Select Discount = choose(aft,.05,.10,.15) + choose(health,.02,.02,.03)
 From  YourTable
```